# How to trigger a docker image everytime a request is received?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud

Suppose you are serving a ML app, now every time a client uploads a file(upto 1.5G), I want to trigger a new docker which contains the ML app, enables the GPU for computation, calculates stuff and returns the output to the client. How does one proceed?

Comment: It's a full project! But have a look to Workflows for the orchestration. For the rest, Cloud Build, AI Platform training with GPU for computation

Comment: You can use [Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/) to build the workflow.

Comment: Are there any tutorials i can follow?